# How do I add a keyboard shortcut to clear scrollback buffer in Windows Terminal?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, terminal, windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-terminal

I'd like to be able to clear my scrollback buffer in Windows Terminal using a keyboard shortcut.

In WSL I can hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> and it does a form-feed (equivalent of `clear -x` command), which clears the screen but only by scrolling the content above up and out of view.

What I'd like to do is, for example, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> (like macOS Terminal) to be able to clear the screen properly (similar to issuing a plain `clear` command) in both WSL and PowerShell.

Is this possible?

**Update**: This is now supported natively in Windows Terminal. I've added my own answer below and self-accepted, but it's a bit buried, so here is a link: https://superuser.com/a/1628815/2924

Comment: Does `CLS` not do what you expect?  I remember it as `C`lear`L`a`S`creen ;)

Comment: Yeah it does in PowerShell. Both `cls` and `clear` are aliases of `Clear-Host` in PS. So what I really need in Windows Terminal is a way to bind the `clear` command to a shortcut, which would work in both WSL and PS.

Comment: What does it matter if it is a "shortcut" or a command? .. that is as long as you can type the same three keys and it works with either system?  I do get what you are saying though.. this still does not answer your question.  I am using WSL1 and I can bind anything that I want using the Linux `alias` command.. for instance.. alias start='explorer.exe' .. then  I can do `start .` just like I do from windows.

Comment: Sometimes I have a command on the prompt and realise I want the screen cleared before I run it. I can hit Ctrl+L and the screen will clear, but leave what I've typed at the prompt in place. I could hit Ctrl+a, Ctrl+k, type `clear`, Ctrl+y to cut the line, clear the screen, then yank (paste) back the result, but I'm lazy. Plus it's just easier to quickly hit a keyboard shortcut for this task - it's a muscle memory thing :)

Comment: Cool :) .. I get it.  This does not happen with my own work flow.  I don't have an answer but I wish you good luck.

Comment: You can do it with Autohotkey, create a hotkey that sends input to the corresponding window filtered by window title and executable.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Update 2021-10-20**: This is now natively supported as of [version 1.12](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/releases/tag/v1.12.2922.0) (in preview at time of writing).

See [PR #10906](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/pull/10906) for full details.

> This adds a new action, `clearBuffer`. It accepts 3 values for the clear
> type:
>
> - `"clear": "screen"`: Clear the terminal viewport content. Leaves the scrollback untouched. Moves the cursor row to the top of the viewport
>   (unmodified).
> - `"clear": "scrollback"`: Clear the scrollback. Leaves the viewport untouched.
> - `"clear": "all"`: (default) Clear the scrollback and the visible viewport. Moves the cursor row to the top of the viewport
>   (unmodified).
> - "Clear Buffer" has also been added to `defaults.json`.

These actions can be invoked from the command palette or can be bound to keyboard shortcuts via the settings UI, and directly in `settings.json` as covered in the [official documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/customize-settings/actions).

[image: Binding a shortcut to the Clear buffer action]

[image: Clear buffer action in settings.json]

[image: Windows Terminal clearBuffer action example]

---

For reference, here's a discussion on the difference between <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>: [What is the difference between Ctrl+L and Cmd+K for clearing the terminal screen?](https://superuser.com/questions/819593/what-is-the-difference-between-ctrll-and-cmdk-for-clearing-the-terminal-screen)

**Longer answer**

According to Mike Griese ([zadjii-msft](https://github.com/zadjii-msft) on GitHub), an engineer working on Windows Terminal:

> To clarify for future me - cmd+k is not something that's being handled by bash or the shell. This is the Terminal itself handling the keybinding, and clearing both the buffer and the scrollback.
>
> You've described a user story that makes sense to me, so I'm gonna put this on the backlog.

Dustin Howett ([DHowett-MSFT](https://github.com/DHowett-MSFT) on GitHub) goes on to say:

> [T]his issue in particular that's thornier than most. For compatibility with Windows console applications that do not expect a terminal to be connected, we need to maintain a text buffer for them to read. That's all. Because we don't have a way to clear that text buffer (from the terminal side), and we just haven't written one yet, it's only more complex than clearing the local screen. It's not a complexity class issue with all of Terminal.

Reference: https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/1882

Comment: This hasn't been released yet?

Comment: @OrangeDog it will be available in 1.12 which is in pre-release preview at the moment. You can grab the preview version here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/p/windows-terminal-preview/9n8g5rfz9xk3#activetab=pivot:overviewtab.

Answer (score 9):

Well this turned into a rabbit-trail-and-a-half ;-) ...

I would have thought this would have been pretty straightforward with the `sendInput` action introduced in Windows Terminal 1.3, but I keep coming up short using that method.  I don't claim to be any expert at keybindings or terminal escape sequences, but I'm trying to muddle through.

First, from `man clear`, the "clear scrollback" sequence is `Esc[3J`.  This works in Windows Terminal via:

- Powershell: `` Write-Output "`e[3J" ``
- bash, zsh, or fish:  `printf '\033[3J'` (or equivalent `echo`)

It, of course, needs to be coupled with the "clear entire screen" sequence (`\033[2J`) and the "cursor to home position" (`\033[H`) (obtained from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37778152/11810933)).

Put it together, and `printf '\033[2J\033[3J\033[H'` gets us the `clear` (without arguments) behavior.

So I would think, given the `sendInput` example in the [Windows Terminal 1.3 release notes](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/releases/tag/v1.3.2382.0) that we could send that escape code via:

```
{ "command": { "action": "sendInput", "input": "\u001B[3J" }, "keys": "ctrl+shift+l"}
```

in the `"actions"` section (formerly `"keybindings"`).  The `\u001b[A` example (up arrow) works fine for me, but the "clear scrollback" results in an error bell in bash and printing `[3J` in fish.  The same occurs for `\u001B[2J` for just trying to clear the screen as well.  If someone can figure out where I'm going wrong on that, I'd love to know.

But ... we *can* rebind the keys in the shells.  However, they probably won't won't be able to tell the difference between <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> for [this reason](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14876639/11810933).  Except for the recent PSReadLine 2.0, which is case-sensitive on key-bindings.

So if you really want to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd> in both PowerShell and Linux shells in WSL, you'll need to do it in two steps:

First, set up a Windows Terminal action to `sendInput` with an unused keycode:

```
"actions":
// formerly "keybindings"
    [
      ...
        { "command": { "action": "sendInput", "input": "\uAC12" }, "keys": "ctrl+shift+l"},
      ...
    ]
}
```

Honestly, I'm not sure what the best way of picking a keycode is.  I just went with something from the [Hangul](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hangul_Syllables) character set (`\uAC12`), since I'm fairly sure I'm never going to run across that in real-life.  Note that [this comment](https://github.com/PowerShell/PSReadLine/issues/639#issuecomment-490927138) recommends using the "[private use](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Unicode/Character_reference/E000-EFFF)" `E000-EFFF` range, but it seemed fairly populated on Windows Terminal, and I'd already settled on Hangul, so I've left the examples below using `\uAC12`.

So then we need to bind `\uAC12` in each shell to send the right escape sequences:

- Bash:

  First, get the key sequence to bind to with `printf '\uAC12' | xxd`, which results in `00000000: eab0 92`.

  Then, using that output, encode the bind command as `bind -x '"\xEA\xB0\x92":"printf \\033[2J\\033[3J\\033[H"'` (`xxd` idea from a comment in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/602924/11810933).)
- Zsh:  It looks to be a bit more involved:

  ```
  function clear-scrollback {
    clear && printf '\e[3J'
    zle && zle .reset-prompt && zle -R
  }
  zle -N clear-scrollback
  bindkey '\uAC12' clear-scrollback
  ```

  (with assist from [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/531178/432493)).
- Fish:  `bind \uAC12 "printf '\033[2J\033[3J\033[H'; commandline -f repaint"`
- PowerShell: `` Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler "$([char]0xAC12)" -ScriptBlock { Write-Output "`e[2J`e[3J"; [Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine]::ClearScreen() } ``.  Assist on the `[char]` casting from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1056978/11810933), and dang if it didn't take me a while to find an [example](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psreadline/set-psreadlinekeyhandler?view=powershell-7.1#example-2--bind-a-key-to-a-script-block) of calling a PSReadline function in a ScriptBlock.
- PowerShell Core: `` Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler "$([char]0xAC12)" -ScriptBlock { Write-Host "`e[2J`e[3J"; [Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine]::ClearScreen() } ``.  Not sure why PowerShell and PowerShell Core behave differently here.

Corrections or suggestions for improvement welcome.

Answer (score 8):

Edit your `~/.bashrc`

```bsh
alias cls='clear && echo -en "\e[3J"'
```

Now you can type `cls` to clear the screen and scrollback inside your bash WSL session.

Edit your Windows Terminal JSON file

```json
"actions": 
[
    // Command to reset terminal and scrollback
    { 
        "command": 
        { 
            "action": "sendInput", "input": "cls\r" 
        }, 
        "keys": "ctrl+k"
    },
]
```

Now pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> will enter the CLS command for you.  For PowerShell or a CMD prompt, the CLS command is already supported by default, so no extra config is necessary.

Comment: Usually I'm not a personal fan of `sendInput` entering commands, since it can be triggered even when not at the prompt.  That said, it's just *so much easier* than my answer that I'd go with your method in this case.

Comment: Worked great. Accepted due to the simplicity of the solution and me being a simple person. :)

Comment: To not clutter your history, make it `"input": " cls\r"` (note the leading space) and in your `~/.bashrc` set [HISTCONTROL](https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/using-bash-history-more-efficiently-histcontrol) to `ignorespace`  or `ignoreboth`.